# Overwrite Branch in Git

Tags: git

Ok using git I want to overwrite my Stage Branch with my UAT branch. after I did the push the code that I wanted removed from Stage is still there. What am I doing wrong?

```
git checkout UAT
git merge -s ours origin/Stage
git push
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to completely override the branch with what's on `UAT`, I'd recommend making a copy of your `Stage` branch, then destroying the `Stage` branch on `origin`, then recreate `Stage` from `UAT`.  Something like:

```
git checkout Stage 
git checkout -b StageCopy 
git push origin StageCopy
```

At this point, you have a copy of `Stage` in case you ever need to revert.

Then destroy `Stage` on `origin` and locally...

```
git push origin :Stage
git branch -D Stage
```

Then copy `UAT` as the "new" `Stage`

```
git checkout UAT
git checkout -b Stage
git push origin Stage
```

At this point, if you're satisfied with what's on `Stage` and you're *absolutely sure* you don't need the old `Stage` (which is now `StageCopy`), you can destroy `StageCopy`:

```
git branch -D StageCopy
git push origin :StageCopy
```

Comment: You probably have/like a 'git co' alias for checkout just like I do, but might be useful to edit it out of the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You are close. Because there is no "theirs" strategy, you have to do some branch hopping. To get Stage to look exactly like UAT, you have to first merge Stage into UAT.

```sh
git checkout UAT
git merge -s ours Stage
```

This will create a "dummy" commit on UAT that makes git think it includes all the history from Stage but actually leaves UAT unchanged. This commit will allow you to merge back into Stage without conflicts, but it shouldn't be pushed.

```sh
git checkout Stage
git merge UAT -m "Overwriting with UAT"
git diff UAT     # returns nothing
```

This will bring Stage in line with UAT without rewriting history.

Answer (score -1):

I think you just did opposite thing - overwritten UAT with Stage. I assume you have pushed all of it into a shared repository and you are not allowed to force push branches as it is required in the @CDub's answer.

You just need revert the merge commit you just done:

```
 $ git checkout UAT
 $ git revert -m1 HEAD
 $ git push
```

After it just merge it correctly:

```
$ git checkout Stage
$ git merge -s ours UAT
$ git push
```